# How to add example for POST body for swagger using Asp .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen, swashbuckle.examples

I am using .Net Core 2.2 and swagger 2.0. I want to add an example body as a part of the documentation for the POST operation. I could not find any support for "POST" with a body in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.

How to add documentation for POST body using .Net Core?